# Change my class (and method) to make it work with two interfaces

Tags: java, interface

I have never programmed with interfaces and I am googling but don't understand it easily. 
What do I have to change in my class `ParseTika` to make it work based on te contract of the `interface` (no changes to the interface is allowed)?  (I am also seeing an unhandeld exception)
(You can assume that the interfaces are correct)

I have deal with two interfaces that are created after my code class is programmed:

**Interface 1:**

How my code is called:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ComponentIndexer {
    IndexedFile indexedFile(Attachment attachment) throws AttachmentParserException;
}
```

**Interface 2:**

What I have to give back:

```
public interface IndexedFile {
    String getName();
    String getTitle();
    String getDescription();
    String getText();
}
```

My class(this was programmed before the interface).

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;


import nl.grm.sm.container.*;
import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
import org.apache.tika.parser.ParseContext;
import org.apache.tika.sax.BodytextHandler;
import org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class ParseTika implements ComponentIndexer, IndexedFile {

    private String text;
    private String title;

    public ParseTika(String text, String title) throws TikaException, IOException, SAXException {
        this.text = text;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public static ParseTika giveObject(Attachment attachment) throws AttachmentParserException {
        try {
            return new ParseTika();
        } catch (IOException | TikaException | SAXException e) {
            throw new AttachmentParserException("Something went wrong.", e);
        }


        //detecting the file type
        BodytextHandler handler = new BodytextHandler();
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
        ParseContext pcontext = new ParseContext();

        AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();

        try (InputStream is = attachment.newInputStream()) {
            parser.parse(is, handler, metadata, pcontext);
        }


        String text2 = handler.toString();
        String[] metadataNames = metadata.names();

        String title2 = "";

        for (String name : metadataNames) {
            if (name.equals("title")) {
                title2 = metadata.get(name);
            }
        }

        return new ParseTika(text2, title2);
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On first look I can see that you have not implemented all methods of your interface in your implementation class (ParseTika)

You need to add the following 3 methods that are missing from your class;

```
IndexedFile indexedFile(Attachment attachment) throws AttachmentParserException{
    //your code here
}

String getName(){
    //your code here
}

String getDescription(){
    //your code here
}
```

You can even leave these implementations as blank for now if you are not clear what you want to write on it.

But if your class `implements` an interface, you need to implement all the methods of that interface in your class. (Unless it is an abstract class, but let's not get into that for now!)

I hope this was helpful!

Comment: just to be sure, do I have to place this code inside the class `ParseTika `?

Answer (score 1):

Let's go step by step.

[Java Documentations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html) says:

> In the Java programming language, an interface is a reference type, similar to a class, that can contain only constants, **method signatures**, default methods, static methods, and nested types.

I emboldened *method signatures* because your interfaces only has method signatures. Methods which does not have a body (the code between { }) and ends with semicolon in interfaces can be called as methed signatures.

> To use an interface, you write a class that implements the interface. When an instantiable class implements an interface, it provides a method body for each of the methods declared in the interface.

You have a class(ParseTika) that implements both of your interfaces. If you read the the blockquote above, only requirement for you to satisfy implementation is providing bodies to your method signatures.

You don't have bodies for:

- IndexedFile indexedFile(Attachment attachment) throws AttachmentParserException;
- String getDescription();
- String getName();